# using GO keyword in SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

i know the use of GO keyword. it sends multiple statements to sql server as a whole group, instead of sending each statement one by one. i hope i am right!

but i want to know that do programmers use it in real applications. like if we create a stored procedure, then that also does the same thing,it also compiles the code and make an execution plan , and send the whole group to the server.

so do we need to specify the GO keyword in the coding of database objects such as triggers, views, stored procedures ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**GO** is a command used for signaling the end of a batch. Note that it is not a T-SQL statement.

**Batch** is a group of one or more Transact-SQL statements sent at the same time from an application to SQL Server for execution

GO is very useful in SQL Server. Though, you need to use it only when is really needed.
So, you need to keep in mind that along with defining a batch using the GO command, you **define the scope** of that specific piece of T-SQL code. The local variables defined in a batch are specific to that batch.

Scope example -

```
DECLARE @STRING1 AS VARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @STRING2 AS VARCHAR(50)

SET @STRING1='BATCH 2'
SET @STRING2='BATCH 3'

SELECT @STRING1 AS RESULT
GO

SELECT @STRING2 AS RESULT
GO
```

Running this will give you error saying @STRING2 is not declared. Because the scope of that variable ends with the GO. So beware of using GO and use smartly.

Source - http://aartemiou.blogspot.com/2009/08/using-go-command-in-sql-server.html

Comment: @sqlchild - It is a logical decision which you need to take depending on the kind of triggers, views and SPs you have in your application.

Comment: On an additional note, if you use ADODB or OleDB for programmatically running queries, using a GO statement will generate an error.  It is a special keyword for use in Query Analyzer/SQL Server Management Studio.  For SSMS, this is configurable in Options - found in the Tools menu.  The "Batch Separator" setting under Query Execution->SQL Server->General holds the keyword GO.

Answer (score 7):

The `GO` keyword signals the end of a batch to SQL Server Management Studio - normally SQL Server Management Studio executes all statements in a single batch, (a batch can be thought of as a round trip to the database), however in certain situations it may be desired to execute statements in different batches (for example the [SET SHOWPLAN_ALL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187735.aspx) statement must be the only statement in a batch)

For example, executing the following script in SQL Server Management Studio:

```
USE StackOverflow
GO
SELECT * FROM Comments
```

Is roughly equivalent to doing the following in C#:

```
using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("USE StackOverflow", conn))
{
    cmd.ExecuteReader();
}
using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Comments", conn))
{
    cmd.ExecuteReader();
}
```

Note that `GO` is **not** a T-SQL keyword, it is only understood by SQL Server Management Studio and other SQL tools.  For example the following wont work and will result in a runtime exception:

```
string cmdText = @"
USE StackOverflow
GO
SELECT * FROM Comments";

using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdText, conn))
{
    cmd.ExecuteReader();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

GO is not a Keyword in SQL.  It's a directive for SSMS and other tools to break a larger script into batches.

Answer (score 4):

To add to what everyone else has stated... you can't actually use GO in a Stored Procedure, Trigger, View, UDF, or even in Dynamic SQL.  It is for use with scripting only.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you're going to be better off using semicolon (;) to separate statements.

Comment: This isn't relevant. GO is a batch delimiter. A semicolon is a statement delimiter. You can have multiple statements in a batch. Incidentally, you don't even need to use the word "GO". GO is set by default in SSMS options. You could theoretically set it to some other word if you wanted to. If you were really evil (@rob_farley) and a colleague left their screen unlocked, you could set it to, oh let's say "SELECT" and watch as chaos and nasty error messages ensue when they come back and start coding again. Every time SSMS sees the word SELECT it thinks "Hey there's the end of the batch!"

Answer (score 1):

No there is no need to specify the GO directive in SQL server.

Answer (score 1):

MSDN [Defines Go](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188037.aspx) as

> Signals the end of a batch of Transact-SQL statements to the SQL Server utilities.

and goes on further to say

> GO is not a Transact-SQL statement; it
>   is a command recognized by the sqlcmd
>   and osql utilities and SQL Server
>   Management Studio Code editor.
>
> SQL Server utilities interpret GO as a
>   signal that they should send the
>   current batch of Transact-SQL
>   statements to an instance of SQL
>   Server. The current batch of
>   statements is composed of all
>   statements entered since the last GO,
>   or since the start of the ad hoc
>   session or script if this is the first
>   GO.

The most common time I use GO is for Object creation Scripts

My create scripts usually follow this pattern

```
USE SomeDatabase
GO

If Exists(SELECT * FROM ...)
 DROP

CREATE PROC as foo
BEGIN
END
GO 

Grant exec on Foo to Bar
```

So the two GOs are important because I want to make sure I'm on the right DB and it won't work without the GO. The second GO is vital otherwise the stored procedure will try to run the grant statement as part of the procedure.