# difference in executing a single line query with and without GO keyword

Tags: c#, .net, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

what's the difference in executing below query with and without GO keyword

```
use hello


use hello
GO
```

i am using use database query, it could be insert, select  or any query.

Comment: Didn't you sort of already ask this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5190405/using-go-keyword-in-sql-server

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5190405/102112

Comment: I assume from your tags this concerns SQL Server 2005, though it would be best to state that in the question itself.  It is also necessary to know what database "client" or API you are using.  Again the tags suggest you may be doing queries programmatically (e.g. ADO.NET), but the syntax "GO" you ask about can be used with an interactive query tool.  GO is not a Transact-SQL command, but rather syntax recognized by **sqlcmd** and isql/osql utilities as signifying the end of a batch of T-SQL commands. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188037.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on how it is executed. If you simply execute `use hello` in SSMS, it is equivalent to

```
use hello;
GO
```

I.e., when you execute a statement by itself, it is being executed as its own batch. However, if you execute the following SSMS:

```
use hello;
GO
Select 'hello'
```

, you are executing two batches which are separated by the `GO` keyword. From C#, outside of using the SQL Server SMO, you cannot execute a script with multiple batches using a Command object (e.g. SqlCommand). I.e., when you use a Command object from C#, it cannot contain the `GO` keyword.

Answer (score 4):

GO isn't actually part of the query for SQL. Tools like SSMS use it to know in a block of statements to send them individidually. So think of GO as a seperator.

So..

```
SELECT ...

GO

SELECT ...
```

Will be sent to SQL as two seperate commands and not just one.

Answer (score 1):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188037.aspx.